# angularjs: chain promises returns a promise instead of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, chain

I have a chain promises and I want to return an object instead of a promise. Instead I get a promise.
This is the function:

```
self.get = function(id) {
    var parameters = [id];
    var orders     = {}
    return DBA.queryAgent("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE " + column_id + " = ?", parameters).then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
    }).then(function(result) {
        order = result;
        return self.getProdutcs(id);
    }).then(function(result) {
        order.Products = result;
        return order;
    });
}
```

I expect that

```
service.get(1)
```

returns an object, I get a promise. Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

> calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise,

It is the way angular is written. Hence, you have to access it like this.

```
 service.get.then(function(result) {
    // whatever
  });
```

Comment: I got it, thanks. I had forgotten the asyncronous fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value by doing the following:

```
  service.get.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);   
  });
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want understand how I can NOT do that.

Comment: The `then()` function returns a promise. It's how they work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: If you don't want it to return a promise then you can run run the command synchronously and block the thread or pass a callback function to the get method and invoke that instead of using an anonymous function. The point of promises is to do neither of those things

Comment: Thanks to both, you are right. I was forgetting the asynchronous fact

Comment: Not sure why my answer didn't get marked as the selected answer or get an upvote :( It contained all the necessary information.

Comment: Because I asked another question. If you do not add the statement "calling the then method of a promise returns a new derived promise" (like upvoted answer did) your answer does not respond to my question.

Comment: I literally said it in the comments :) I then linked you to the documentation which explains it even further. Oh well.